# Итерировать OrderedDict

Tags: python, dict

У меня есть цикл, который добавляет значения в OrderedDict:

```
qs_catalog_items = SyTree.objects.filter(visible=True).order_by('parent_id', 'so')

od = OrderedDict()

for obj in qs_catalog_items:
    if obj.parent_id in od:
        od[obj.parent_id].items.append(obj)
    else:
        obj.items = []
        od[obj.id] = obj
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  как мне перебрать (и распечатать) его таким образом, чтобы в каждом элементе OD будет свойство типа list.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict ?

Answer (score 1):

Перебирать так:

```
for k, v in od.items():
    print(k, v)
```

---

Не уверен, что я правильно понял. Отпишитесь, пожалуйста, в комментарии.

Попробуйте так:

```
qs_catalog_items = SyTree.objects.filter(visible=True).order_by('parent_id', 'so')

od = OrderedDict()

for obj in qs_catalog_items:
    if obj.parent_id not in od:
        od[obj.parent_id] = []

     od[obj.parent_id].append(obj)
```

Comment: Очень странно, выдает ошибку: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Это перебор для вашего варианта кода в вопросе `print(k, v.items)` (я не был уверен, что он правильный, поэтому сделал свой вариант с заполнением). В случаи моего заполнения, используйте: `print(k, v)`. Метод словаря `items()` возвращает список кортежей из двух элементов: ключа и значения